# Clojure error: Unable to resolve symbol: update in this context

Tags: clojure

This is the code I copied from an answer on another post on this website:

```
(def data [[1 1 1 3] [2 2 2 3] [3 2 1 1] [4 3 3 4]])
(def replacements {1 "joe" 2 "fred" 3 "martha"})

(defn test
[]
    (mapv (fn [row] (update row 1 replacements)) data)
)
```

when I call (test) in REPL, it shows the following error:

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: update in this context

Why is it that Clojure does not know the update function?

Comment: Check what version of Clojure you are using. update was added in 1.7

Comment: If you are on <1.7, you can use `update-in` (e.g. `(update-in row [1] replacements)`)

Answer (score 1):

You get this error if you call `update` from clojure 1.6 or earlier.

`update` was added in 1.7, before that you had to use `update-in`

try `(clojure-version)` and see what you're using.

*(as it says in the comments by cfrick and dpassen)*

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the repl.  It works when I try it:

```
(def data [[1 1 1 3] [2 2 2 3] [3 2 1 1] [4 3 3 4]])
(def replacements {1 "joe" 2 "fred" 3 "martha"})
(defn test []
  (mapv (fn [row] (update row 1 replacements)) data) )

(test) => [[1 "joe" 1 3] [2 "fred" 2 3] [3 "fred" 1 1] [4 "martha" 3 4]]
```

Another option (my favorite) is to work on such code in a temporary testing namespace (e.g. `tst.demo.core`), so you have the full editor available, and it is easier to make sure everything is loaded/reloaded correctly.

I also highly recommend the `lein-test-refresh` [plugin for lein.](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh)

Another option is to make a new empty directory and start a repl there:

```
~/expr > mkdir sally
~/expr > cd sally
~/expr/sally > lein repl
user=> (def data [[1 1 1 3] [2 2 2 3] [3 2 1 1] [4 3 3 4]])
#'user/data
user=> (def replacements {1 "joe" 2 "fred" 3 "martha"})
#'user/replacements
user=> (defn test []
  #_=>   (mapv (fn [row] (update row 1 replacements)) data) )
WARNING: test already refers to: #'clojure.core/test in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/test
#'user/test
user=> (test)
[[1 "joe" 1 3] [2 "fred" 2 3] [3 "fred" 1 1] [4 "martha" 3 4]]
```

---

***Update***

Note that in Clojure the file name & directory structure ***must*** match the namespace declaration in each file.  Thus a file like `./src/fred/core.clj` ***must*** have a namespace like `fred.core`, where `./src` is a subdirectory of the main project directory (where `project.clj` lives).

Comment: I restarted Eclipse and it still doesn't work. Does it have to do with the fact that I renamed my a3.core namespace to (ns a3.menu) ? Sorry I'm very new to Clojure

Comment: Very likely if you did not change the `(ns a3.core ...)` declaraction to match the new file name; see the update.